# Pass different instances based on constructor parametername using AutoFac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

I have a class like this (WebApi 2 Controller):

```
class DatabaseAnalysisController (IDatabase databaseOne, 
    IDatabase databaseTwo) : ApiController
```

And a class like this:

```
class Database : IDatabase
```

Now I have two instances:

```
Database databaseOne = new Database("one");
Database databaseTwo = new Database("two");
```

I don't want `DatabaseAnalysis` to have any dependencies upon Autofac. But I want to use Autofac to inject on based on parameter name of the constructor.

I am using `Autofac.WebApi` to register my controllers.

```
builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

But after that this won't work, because `databaseOne` and `databaseTwo` are both `IDatabase`.

```
builder.RegisterInstance(new Database("one")).As<IDatabase>();
```

Is it possible for Autofac to inject `databaseOne` into `databaseOne` of the constructor of `DatabaseAnalysis` (and also `databaseTwo` into `databaseTwo`) ?

And if so, how? :P

Comment: Does `builder.Register<DatabaseAnalysisController>(c => new DatabaseAnalysisController(new Database("one"), new Database("two"))).InstancePerLifetimeScope();` work?

Comment: That works. But I would like to make it work purely on parameterNames, and not having to use the DatabaseAnalysisController in the registration.

Comment: Does @Evk's solution fit the bill?

Comment: Make sure that you aren't violating the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). A good check for this is asking yourself what happens when you swap the database arguments (thus injecting db2 into the `databaseOne` parameter and vise versa). If this breaks your controller, you are violating LSP. In that case, each database should get _its own_ abstraction.

Comment: @Steven, you are basically saying I should go for NightOwl888 's answer ;-)

Comment: @mjwills Yes, but I dislike the disadvantage of having to "call" his extension on every registration.

Comment: No, I'm not saying that. What I'm saying is: find out if you have a LSP violation. If you do, @NightOwl888's answer is one of the possible solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have multiple instances with the same interface and type - you need to register them with a name:

```
builder.RegisterInstance(new Database("one")).Named<IDatabase>("databaseOne");
builder.RegisterInstance(new Database("two")).Named<IDatabase>("databaseTwo");
```

Then you can register your `DatabaseAnalysisController` like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<DatabaseAnalysis>().WithParameter(
    (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(IDatabase), 
    (pi, ctx) => ctx.ResolveNamed<IDatabase>(pi.Name));
```

You can make an extension method to perform such registrations like this:

```
public static class AutofacExtensions {
    public static IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit, TReflectionActivatorData, TStyle> WithNamedParameter<TLimit, TReflectionActivatorData, TStyle>(this IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit, TReflectionActivatorData, TStyle> registration, Type targetType)
        where TReflectionActivatorData : ReflectionActivatorData {
        return registration.WithParameter(
            (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == targetType,
            (pi, ctx) => ctx.ResolveNamed(pi.Name, targetType));
    }
}
```

To do that for all controllers, do it like this:

```
builder.RegisterApiControllers().WithNamedParameter(typeof(IDatabase));
```

Comment: I would like to have it work on any class which it gets injected to. So I do not want to name that class during registration. I want to have it work on just the target parameter name.

Comment: @frankhommers then try to do `RegisterApiControllers().WithParameter(...)` where `WithParameter` you can take from second block of code in my answer. I cannot test now if it will work, but you can give it a try. Of course before that register both databases as named instances like above.

Comment: Well you register api controllers with `RegisterApiControllers`, so you register those other classes somehow also. Just add `WithParameter` to their registrations too I guess. You can make an extension method out of it ('WithParametersOfType<T>` something like that).

Comment: Thanks. But I see there is one disadvantage to this approach. I need to call this extension on every registration. So it won't automatically work when I add a IDatabase databaseOne parameter to another existing class.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making the dependency that is injected depend on constructor parameter names, an alternative way to deal with these dependencies would just be to make the interfaces generic. Then the generic closing type (`T`) would determine which `IDatabase<T>` to inject.

```
interface IDatabase<T> {}
class Database1 : IDatabase<Database1>
class Database2 : IDatabase<Database2>
```

In your services:

```
class SomeService1
{
    public SomeService1(IDatabase<Database1> database)
    {
        // set database to private variable
    }
}

class SomeService2
{
    public SomeService2(IDatabase<Database2> database)
    {
        // set database to private variable
    }
}
```

Which could be registered like:

```
builder.RegisterType<IDatabase<Database1>>().As<Database1>();
builder.RegisterType<IDatabase<Database2>>().As<Database2>();
```

Although `IDatabase<T>` is shared between implementations, the .NET type system (and therefore Autofac) sees `IDatabase<Database1>` as a completely different type than `IDatabase<Database2>`. This means the types are automatically put into the right place, but it also means that you can't just swap one for another in your application. So, whether this will work for you depends on your specific use case.

Comment: But then using interface doesn't make much sense - you can as well inject `Database1` and `Database2` classes directly.

Comment: This is one way of doing it, but that is basically defining another type instead of injecting by name. Not what I was aiming for...

Comment: @Evk - If you inject the concrete type directly, the only way to mock it for testing would be to inherit it. Not as flexible of a solution as this is.